# My samsung s2 is being spammed & I have 2 apps that I can't uninstall. Please help

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-2, samsung, spam

My son was playing games on my samsung and now I am being spammed all day long for the past week. I have installed Airpush Detector and it said that they don't detect any push ads on my phone from apps. But I noticed that I have 2 apps on my phone that I have never seen before. One is called Nova & it has a pic of what looks like the No.O.V.A. game icon & has HD on the icon as well. I didn't install this on my phone and there is no option to uninstall it. It is labeled as a default on my phone. I also have an app called Top HD Games on my phone that I didn't install and am unable to uninstall it as it also is classified as a default setting on my phone. The icon for this is an XBox game controller. Has anyone else seen this before? I can't find anything in the google play store and can't figure out how to get rid of these. I uninstalled all games on my phone except for the Angry Birds series, Finding Nemo game, bubble blaster and zoo club. I would really appreciate anyone's help.Thanks!

Comment: *Airpush detector* IMHO is limited to Airpush detection. Though that's one of the worst, there's also Leadbolt, and some more. I'd recommend checking with [AppBrain Ad Detector](http://www.appbrain.com/app/AppBrain-Ad-Detector/com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.detector), which finds almost all of the ad-network-modules. To name an alternative: [Lookout Ad Network Detector](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Lookout-Ad-Network-Detector/com.lookout.addetector) is similarly effective. AFAIR, both also offer to uninstall the "bad app".

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to presume this was a side-loaded app with a potential malware payload, since you mention you cannot find it on Google Play Store.

First step is to see if the application can be prevented from uninstall because it has set itself up as a Device Administrator, sort of a protected app.
See Settings>Security>Device Administrators, and deactivate both or either, if listed. You may need to provide a Device Administrator password to do so. Then try to see if they will uninstall normally.

If not a Device Administrator, you may still attempt to uninstall normally, just finding it in a different list, the "All" list.
See Settings>Application Manager>All(far right column)
Find the application(s) in the list. Try to uninstall this way, or at the very least "Disable" or "Turn Off" if those operations are possible.

To prevent side-loading apps in the future, see
Settings>Security>Unknown Sources, and uncheck.

Comment: All valid points (+1 from me). Just if the son decides to side-load something again, triggering the "unknown sources" checkbox will not prevent that (he will just trigger it again).